# How to programmatically create topics using kafka-python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-python, kafka-topic

I am getting started with Kafka and fairly new to Python. I am using this library named [`kafka-python`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html) to communicate with my Kafka broker. Now I need to dynamically create a topic from my code, from the docs what I see is I can call `create_topics()` method to do so, however I am not sure, how will I get an instance of this class. I am not able to understand this from the docs.

Can some one help me with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You first need to create an instance of [`KafkaAdminClient`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.admin.KafkaAdminClient). The following should do the trick for you:

```
from kafka.admin import KafkaAdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = KafkaAdminClient(
    bootstrap_servers="localhost:9092", 
    client_id='test'
)

topic_list = [NewTopic(name="example_topic", num_partitions=1, replication_factor=1)]
admin_client.create_topics(new_topics=topic_list, validate_only=False)
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`confluent_kafka`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) client which is a lightweight wrapper around [librdkafka](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka):

```
from confluent_kafka.admin import AdminClient, NewTopic


admin_client = AdminClient({"bootstrap_servers": "localhost:9092"})
topic_list = [NewTopic("example_topic", 1, 1)]
admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
```

Comment: You may need to "read" the topic before making sure its created:

```
res = admin_client.create_topics(topic_list)
for topic, f in res.items():
    f.result()
```